# Access Denied while Applying S3 Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied

Am new to AWS. i have created bucket for static hosting and generated my bucket policy as mentioned below

[image: Policy Script]

But when am trying to save, it gives Access Denied error.
[image: Access Denied]

And for your information am the owner of bucket and the root user.

Comment: Please do not use images for providing textual information, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First try this command,
`aws s3 ls`

This will tell you that you are able to access s3 services or not.

If it works than try to add that specific bucket in the `resource` section of your policy like below

```
"Resource": [
        "BUCKET_NAME",
        "BUCKET_NAME/*"
       ]
```

I hope this helps!